# Conditionally execute a template in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a pipeline with several template steps that I want to run based on a condition. These templates need to be run if a specific repository resource exists.

To attempt to achieve this I have done:

First get a reference to the repository resource that might or might not exist.

```
variables:
  securityRepositoryRef: $[ resources.repositories['security_repo'].ref ]
```

My build steps:

```
steps:
- ${{ if contains(variables['securityRepositoryRef'], 'refs') }}:
        - template: security_setup.yml@security_repo
          parameters:
             buildType: 'abcd_1234'
```

And this would in theory work perfectly, however the if statement doesn't seem to behave as expected.

Further testing I have tried:

```
steps:
- ${{ if contains(variables['securityRepositoryRef'], 'refs') }}:
    - script: |
        echo securityRepositoryRef contains refs
        echo securityRepositoryRef: $(securityRepositoryRef)
- ${{ else }}:
     - script: |
        echo securityRepositoryRef does not contain refs
        echo securityRepositoryRef: $(securityRepositoryRef)
```

and the output of this is:

```
securityRepositoryRef does not contain refs
securityRepositoryRef: refs/heads/feature/jira-1234
Finishing: CmdLine
```

Which makes no sense. This is not executing the conditional correctly.

To combat this for a **script** I could use a condition like:

```
- script: |
    echo securityRepositoryRef contains refs
    echo securityRepositoryRef : $(securityRepositoryRef)
  condition: contains(variables['securityRepositoryRef'], 'refs')
```

Which works perfectly at runtime. My problem then is that a **template** cannot have conditions.

**EDIT**
While it doesn't change what I'm trying to accomplish with a conditional template step, it's worth giving background on the scenario. The YAML that my team control is a generic template build script that many teams use. Other teams define their resources and call a template with a number of parameters.

From there a `buildType` parameter is used to build the maven/gradle/msbuild etc build. Long story short, I don't have control on which resources are used and the code that I want to conditionally run is only applicable for some teams.

A parameter could resolve this problem but it would require other teams to make a change which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to expand a template from a repository resource based on the condition whether the repository resource exists/is defined in the YAML pipeline or not, because the template needs to be determined to be expanded or not during **compile time**, and the condition should not be based on the evaluation of any **runtime** variable, whose value can only be processed **after** compile time.

For this, would you consider using other conditions like the evaluation of a parameter like the sample below?

```
parameters:
- name: secruity_repo_ref
  type: string
  default: main
  values:
  - main
  - refs/heads/feature/jira-1234
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: security_repo
    name: Security Repository
    ref: ${{ parameters.secruity_repo_ref }}
    type: git
variables:
  - name: securityRepositoryRef
    value: $[resources.repositories.security_repo.ref]
steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.secruity_repo_ref, 'refs/heads/feature/jira-1234') }}:
  - checkout: self
  - checkout: security_repo
  - template: security_setup.yml@security_repo
- ${{ else }}:
  - checkout: self
  - script: |
      echo securityRepository is not used
```

You can select the parameter value before running the pipeline so as to decide whether to expand the steps in the template.

[image]

> In each run, the metadata for a repository resource is available to all jobs in the form of **runtime** variables.
>
> In a pipeline, template expression variables (`${{ variables.var }}`) get processed at compile time, **before** runtime starts.

For the [conditional incertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) (`if`, `elseif` and `else`), which only works when using template expression `${{ <expression> }}` to evaluate the variable `resources.repositories.<Alias>.ref`, we will see it is not expanded as expected. It can be observed if we `echo securityRepositoryRef in compile time: ${{ variables.securityRepositoryRef }}`, which is expanded as `resources.repositories.security_repo.ref` rather than `refs/heads/main`.

If we use runtime expression `$[ <expression> ]` to evaluate the variable `resources.repositories.<Alias>.ref` in `condition` section of a stage of job to extend a YAML template in the repository resource, we need to make sure the repository resource exists. Otherwise, the complete pipeline will fail to expand due to missing template during **compile time**.

Therefore, it doesn't seem to be a good idea to determine whether to expand a template or not according to the **existence** of any resource.

Here are some documents for your reference. Hope the analysis could help.

[Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

[Expressions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

[Define YAML resources for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#variables-2)

Comment: So, in essence this isn't possible to check?

Comment: If you use template expression to check, it is not possible to check if the resource exists, as the value is not expanded as expected during compile time. If you use runtime expression to check, you have to make sure the resource exists; then, there is no meaning to check if the resource exists.

Comment: OK, is there a better way to conditionally execute a template, conditional on the repository resource having been defined?

Comment: Hi there, I have updated the answer with a possible workaround for you. Have you got a chance to check it together with other answers under this topic? Hope these suggestions can meet your expectations.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't in this case. The YAML that my team control is a generic template build script that many teams use. Other teams define their resources and call a template with a number of parameters. From there a `buildType` parameter is used to build the maven/gradle/msbuild etc build. Long story short, I don't have control on which resources are used and the code that I want to conditionally run is only applicable for **some** teams. A parameter could resolve this problem but it would require other teams to make a change.

Comment: The conditionality as per my question was just my thinking, if there is an alternative method to achieve a **conditional template** let me know.

Comment: As it is possible to add a runtime condition to a script, is it possible to execute a template from a script?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps Pipeline's design is limited regarding the conditional execution of templates based on the existence of a repository resource:

- Using template expressions ([`${{ variables.var }}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)) to check if a resource exists is not feasible. That is because these expressions are evaluated at compile time, and the value of the resource is not expanded as expected during this phase.
- Using [runtime expressions (`$[ variables.var ]`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) requires the resource to exist beforehand. However, this defeats the purpose of checking for the resource's existence, since you must make sure of its presence for the pipeline to run successfully.

So the question is how to conditionally execute a template based on whether the repository resource has been defined.

You added:

> `security_repo` does not exist when the repository resource has not been defined.
> That is a generic build script that should be able to run with or without the existence of the `security_repo` repository resource.

So, if `security_repo` does not exist, the pipeline will fail at compile time because it cannot find the template (`security_setup.yml`) referenced in the repository. That situation arises even before the condition in the template is evaluated.

Make sure `security_setup.yml` is always accessible, regardless of the existence of `security_repo`. That could mean placing the template in a location that is always available to the pipeline.

Use a pre-validation step that checks for the existence of `security_repo` or relevant conditions and sets a pipeline variable.
Then, use this variable to conditionally execute the steps within the universally accessible `security_setup.yml` template.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: PreValidation
  steps:
  - script: |
      # Check for the existence of security_repo or relevant conditions
      # Set a pipeline variable based on the result
      # Example:
      if [ condition ]; then
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=executeSecuritySteps]true"
      else
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=executeSecuritySteps]false"
      fi

- template: security_setup.yml
  parameters:
    executeSecuritySteps: $(executeSecuritySteps)
```

In the `security_setup.yml` template:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: executeSecuritySteps
  default: false

steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.executeSecuritySteps, true) }}:
  - script: |
      # Security steps to be executed
```

That would avoid the limitation of the template's existence by ensuring that the `security_setup.yml` is always accessible, regardless of the state of `security_repo`. The conditionality is then managed within the template based on a variable set in a pre-validation step.

---

> in your example within `security_setup.yml`, my steps would include running a template not a script. So the same behaviour would occur, just one layer deeper.

That... does add another layer of complexity to the situation. The core challenge is to conditionally include a nested template based on the existence of a repository resource. Given the limitations of Azure DevOps Pipeline's template expansion and runtime evaluation, You might consider a pre-pipeline script for dynamic generation: Write a script that checks for the existence of the `security_repo` repository. Based on this check, the script dynamically generates the entire Azure DevOps Pipeline YAML, including or excluding the reference to the nested template.
Use the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) to trigger a pipeline run with the dynamically generated YAML content.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check for the existence of 'security_repo'
# Replace with actual logic, such as a git command or API call
if [ -d "/path/to/security_repo" ]; then
    # Include the nested template in the generated YAML
    cat > generated_pipeline.yml <<EOL
steps:
- template: security_setup.yml
EOL
else
    # Exclude the nested template and replace with an alternative step
    cat > generated_pipeline.yml <<EOL
steps:
- script: echo 'No security_repo found'
EOL
fi

# Use Azure DevOps REST API to trigger the pipeline with the generated YAML
# Replace with actual API call, including authentication
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d @generated_pipeline.yml \
     "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
```

The Azure DevOps pipeline (example for `security_setup.yml`):

```yaml
# security_setup.yml
steps:
- template: nested_template.yml
```

By dynamically generating the entire pipeline YAML outside of Azure DevOps and then triggering the pipeline with this YAML, you would circumvent the limitation of compile-time evaluation. The decision to include or exclude the nested template is made before the pipeline YAML is processed by Azure DevOps.

Comment: in your example within `security_setup.yml`, my steps would include running a template not a script. So the same behaviour would occur, just one layer deeper.

Comment: @Ben I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Did this work for you? Because this has the same problem behaviour that I described in the question, `${{ if eq(parameters.includeNestedTemplate, true) }}` is not executed at runtime so this never runs the `nested_template.yml`

Comment: @Ben True. I have revised the solution (not tested though)

Answer (score 0):

The variable: **$[ resources.repositories['security_repo'].ref ]** will expand at runtime.

And the if expression will expand at compile time.

So the Repo resources variable is not able to pass to the if expression successfully.

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly meet your requirement(get the ref value from the repo resources and use it in the if expression).

For a workaround, you can add a Powershell task in first Pipeline to run the Rest API to trigger the pipeline and pass the repo resources ref value to the second pipeline. The second pipeline can use parameters to accept the value and pass to the if expression.

The Parameters Value can pass to if expression at compile time.

For example:

**First Pipeline:**

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: security_repo
      type: git
      ref: main
      name: reponame
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
 securityRepositoryRef: $[ resources.repositories['security_repo'].ref ]

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $token = "$(pat)"
      echo $newvalue
      $url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{Projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineRunID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
      
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
      
      $JSON = "
      {
        
      
      
        `"resources`": {
          `"repositories`": {
            `"self`": {
              `"ref`": `"refs/heads/master`"
            }
          }
        },
        `"templateParameters`": {
          `"ref`":`"$(securityRepositoryRef)`"
         },
      
      
      
      }"
      
      
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

**Second Pipeline:**

```
parameters:
- name: ref
  type: string
  default: test


resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: security_repo
      type: git
      ref: ${{ parameters.ref }}
      name: reponame
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps: 
- ${{ if contains(parameters.ref, 'refs') }}:
  - script: |
      echo securityRepositoryRef contains refs
      echo securityRepositoryRef: ${{ parameters.ref }}
- ${{ else }}:
  - script: |
      echo securityRepositoryRef does not contain refs
      echo securityRepositoryRef: ${{ parameters.ref }}
```

The second Pipeline will get the target ref value and checkout the repo content corresponding to ref

Comment: Please see my edit in the question for some background on the scenario here. This would work well if I had control over the "first pipeline" script that you have referenced in your example but this is not the case.